Wait all image assets and network images to build before displaying
I have a screen that is basically composed of multiple images (think mosaic) some are coming from assets in the app itself others are network images. Eg, Network image for a Circle Avatar, bottom image is a square coming from assets folder, png images etc etc.
The thing is, when I navigate to that screen, flutter automatically start displaying it and the images comes one by one (not necessarily one by one but in chunks), so the user can see the screen "building" with images popping here and there.
I wanted to know whats the best practice/approach to make sure that the screen only becomes visible once the screen is built (all widgets and images placed in the right place)

You might want to look into pre-loading your images.
Check out this question and see if it helps.

"preload assets images before build"

ps: question was asked years ago, do check Official Flutter Documentation for more details.

"precacheImage function"


but precaching (unless I understood wrong) will cache the images and make them load fast, doesn't mean they won't be popping in different times until the build is complete (so the user will still see images showing up in different times until final load), no? Specially if each asset and image have different sizes (again I might be wrong in my understanding)

yep you are right, pre-caching helps your images load faster but that alone won't help images from "popping" at different times.
To smoothen the user experience consider using skeleton loaders or loading indicators and fade-in animations, pre-caching your images will create an illusion for the users that images are loaded faster since they are fetched from the memory rather than a network.
ps: even app's like Instagram use loading indicators because of Network limitations, Device performance and other factors.
